# Copy tables from Excel to Word, keeping the format

Tags: excel, ms-word, styles, office-js, sheetjs

I like to copy a table from Excel to Word using either office-js or sheet-js, both approaches work, but it does not copy the formatting applied to the Excel table. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: «Is there a way to do this?» Yes, but since you haven't posted your code, no-one can tell you what changes you need to make...

Comment: What code have you tried so far if it doesn't copy the formatting applied?